# Why isn't this jQuery css() working?

Tags: jquery

I have a linked stylesheet with the following:

```
.dirContent {width: 190px, padding: 10px;)
```

I am running this script:

```
var npad = $(".dirContent").css("padding");
alert(npad);
```

...But it doesn't work - it returns a blank alert box.  Now if I run this script:

```
var npad = $(".dirContent").css("width");
alert(npad);
```

It returns "190px", the alert displays the correct value.

Thoughts?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135922/jquery-and-setting-css-with-shorthand

Comment: I have no problems with this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ae5aA/)

Comment: `.dirContent {width: 190px, padding: 10px;)` <-- sould be `;` and `}`

Comment: @roxon There is also a comma where a semi-colon should be...

Comment: @AndrewJackman how come this works?

Comment: I think the issue is that it is not showing up on firefow...but works on chrome

Comment: It works in Chrome, but not in IE9.

Comment: @TimMedora padding in IE9 is an alias for padding-left,-top,..., and rendering it using these properties. Don't know for firefox.

Comment: @roasted - I'm aware that it's an alias...IE9 has no problem setting it, but retrieval behaves inconsistently. See my answer.

Comment: @TimMedora sorry, didn't see your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems I see:

- malformed CSS (covered in other answers)
- inconsistent handling of [shorthand properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135922/jquery-and-setting-css-with-shorthand)

Essentially, *retrieving* shorthand properties works inconsistently across browsers. In Chrome, querying the "padding" property returns a single part string ("1px") if all 4 sides are padded equally, and a 4 part ("1px 2px 3px 4px") string if the padding is different on any of the sides.

But IE9 returns nothing. Firefox 18 returns nothing.

```
var npad = $(".dirContent").css("padding");
alert(npad);
npad = $(".dirContent").css("padding-left");
alert(npad);
```

Try this sample in a few browsers and you should see the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/XDL3N/1/

If you think about it, this behavior makes sense. While shorthand is great for setting properties, it's far less useful for *getting* them. You would need to parse the multi-segment string to do anything useful with it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It may have been months before I realized I couldn't use shorthand css.

KCCO!

Comment: No problem! I've run into the same thing before.

Comment: Ah... and my code isn't this sloppy... I was jotting (wrongly), and I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a `,` to terminate a CSS property.

```
.dirContent {width: 190px; padding: 10px;}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9K6zR/)

Answer (score 0):

Your css property is malformed, it must be:

```
.dirContent {width: 190px; padding: 10px;}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XDL3N/