# JQuery Add Multiple CSS Variables

Tags: jquery, css

http://liveweave.com/KDveAy

I'm trying to figure out how to add multiple variables to a single css property like so...

```
'border' : divborder + divborderstyle + bcolor,
```

equal to...

```
border: 3px solid black;
```

However the code doesn't work. I was wondering if this is possible, or am I going to have to define border-color, border-style, etc instead?

```
var bcolor = $('input[name=bcolor]').val(),
    bgcolor = $('input[name=bgcolor]').val(),
    divborderstyle = $('#divborderstyle').val(),
    divborder = $('#divborder').val();

$(gen_box).css({
     'position'  : 'absolute',
     'top'       : y_begin,
     'left'      : x_begin,
     'width'     : width,
     'height'    : height,
     'border'    : divborder + divborderstyle + bcolor,
     'background': bgcolor
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is there is no space separator between the components

```
$(gen_box).css({
     'position'  : 'absolute',
     'top'       : y_begin,
     'left'      : x_begin,
     'width'     : width,
     'height'    : height,
     'border'    : divborder + ' ' + divborderstyle + ' ' + bcolor,
     'background': bgcolor
})
```

or

```
$(gen_box).css({
     'position'  : 'absolute',
     'top'       : y_begin,
     'left'      : x_begin,
     'width'     : width,
     'height'    : height,
     'border-color'    : bcolor,
     'border-style'    : divborderstyle,
     'border-width'    : divborder,
     'background': bgcolor
})
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery allows you to set css properties using shorthand. See this answer:

[jQuery and Setting CSS with Shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135922/jquery-and-setting-css-with-shorthand)

You are not including the necessary spaces in your border shorthand. Try this:

```
$(gen_box).css({
     'position'  : 'absolute',
     'top'       : y_begin,
     'left'      : x_begin,
     'width'     : width,
     'height'    : height,
     'border'    : divborder + ' ' + divborderstyle + ' ' + bcolor,
     'background': bgcolor
})
```